# Android scaleable text sizes?

Tags: android, android-2.1-eclair

I've got a really simple UI, I just want to display a number in the center of the screen, as large as I can, I have the following layout xml

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:textSize="200sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
```

This works fine when I have numbers such as 1, 2, 3, and so forth, but if I use 100 the it displays it like :

```
10
0
```

Is there anyway of easily making the text as large as I can but force it onto one line? Can the text size be determined by the text being displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try `android:singleLine="true"` also you can try to set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to wrap the content